Voltage reference 1/f noise datasheet comparison
I would like to compare the 1/f noise of the voltage references LT1021 and LTC6655. The LTC6655 has a spec of 0.25 ppm (0.1-10Hz) and the LT1021 has 3uV_pp (0.1-10Hz).
I assume these datasheet specifications are not normalized to the output voltage.
Is is then correct that I need to divide these noise specs by the output voltage to get a fair comparison of these voltage references?
In this case the LT1021 would even be superior to the LTC6655, because it has 7V output voltage versus the LTC6655 which has only 2.5V output voltage.

You are confusing ppm (=1e-6=micro) and pp (peak-to-peak)

I don't see where I should be confusing ppm and pp?

When you try to divide 3uVpp by 6.6 and you obtain 0.45 ppm, it should be 0.45 uVrms instead (no ppms here). That is what I meant, but indeed doesn't appear like you confused ppm and pp there. Sorry.

ppm is a relative unit, it means 1e-6 times the output voltage. ppm literally means the same as µ or 1e-6.
It does not say whether the resulting number is a peak-to-peak of rms number. Infact the LTC6655 lists a ppm(p-p) rating and a ppm(rms) rating, albeit for different parts of the spectrum.
Both reference list comparable specs in the first section. 1ppm(p-p) for the 1021 and 0.25ppm(p-p) for the 6655.
The 6655 is thus approximately 4x more stable (better). It also is more stable over temperature.
